# How to show code like dev websites in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting

I would like to find out how to show code in a way like on StackOverflow or other developer websites. When I mean show code I mean it like this.

```
    Some sample Code
```

I see it on lots of developer websites and would like to know how to do this.

Comment: Use the HTML `<code>` tag - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_computercode_elements.asp

Comment: This only applies the font, I want the grey background too.

Comment: You can change that in your CSS

Comment: what values do I use in the css

Comment: `background-color` is you want to change the background

Comment: What value do I change that too?

Comment: I've just added an answer with the code you need.

Answer (score 5):

Advice: read some tutorials and learn HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

However [here's](https://jsbin.com/gunowejoni/edit?html,output) a fully working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/default.min.css">

</head>
<body>

  <pre>
    <code class="hljs java">
      public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        }
      }
    </code>
  </pre>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
  <script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how it works. You write *computer code* inside `<code>` elements. You wrap `<code>` elements with `<pre>` elements to preserve white space, new lines, etc.

Then you should syntax highlight (also known as colorizing) the code. For that you are better off using a 3rd party library. There are numerous libraries that can do that:

- Highlight.js (the one I've used here)
- [Prism](http://prismjs.com/)
- [SyntaxHighlighter](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter)
- etc.

Some of these libraries let you choose the *color scheme* for your code block too. [Here's](https://jsbin.com/boyijikeyo/1/edit?html,output) the same code with a different color scheme:

The only line changed to apply the new color scheme is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/darcula.min.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the HTML code tag - `<code>`.

You can edit how is appears in CSS, maybe something like this...

```
code {
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
}
```

Comment: No problem, you can mark it as the correct answer if this helped solve your problem.